# Set a Rails environment variable locally (Mac OS X)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, bash, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I'm trying to set environment variables in Rails. I'm following these docs: http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

One option it gives is to save environment variables in your `~/.bashrc`, using this syntax:

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME="myname@gmail.com"
```

I tried adding exactly this to my `~/.bashrc`. Then I stop my rails server, close my terminal, open my terminal, start rails server. The environment variable still doesn't seem to be available.

I've checked if it is available by doing `rails console` in my project root folder, and trying `> ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] # => outputs nil`

How can I set an environment variable locally (in development) so that my Rails project has access to it?

Comment: are you using `zsh` ?

Comment: I don't know what `zsh` is, so I'm assuming not

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I dont know which shell you are using. In case of `bash` , you can write this in your `~/.bashrc` file

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME=abc@bah.com
```

then do this in terminal

```
 source ~/.bashrc
```

Now, check it console . I am sure it will be there .

Comment: you're awesome! thank you. Never knew about source ~/.bashrc, it turned out i had a bug further up in my code and `source` showed it.

Comment: yes, i guess you also have to fix syntax. quotes are not required.

Comment: @DonnyP if the above solution works for you, i would be happy if you mark my solution as "answer" otherwise its okay.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file: config/initializers/settings.rb

```
GMAIL_USERNAME = case Rails.env
  when 'development' then 'myname@gmail.com'
end
```

Restart your app and console.

You should be able to access it wherever you want:

```
> GMAIL_USERNAME
=> 'myname@gmail.com'
```